# WebRtc JS support on ChromeCast?

Tags: webrtc, chromecast, peer-connection

Does ChromeCast support WebRtc and Peer Connection API? If yes, is there an example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code is shared, but the APIs differ. In short, NO.